# Episode titles of "Luna"

Tags: tv, languages

An answer to this [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/255004/childrens-sci-fi-tv-series-from-the-80s-with-a-man-in-a-black-shiny-helmet-pe) reminded me of the children's science fiction show [Luna](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0180370/), shown on ITV in 1983 - 1984 (and also apparently broadcast in New Zealand). Although I've only ever seen the show on blurry VHS tapes (I'm not old enough to have seen it on original broadcast) I was quite captivated by it when I was young.

One of its most distinctive features was the futuristic language, Technotalk, that the characters spoke. It was a little like Orwell's Newspeak in some ways ("good" was "ok", "bad" was "non-ok', and "very good" was "ultra-ok"), and was characterised by the formation of new words from standard English words (such as a "child" being a "diminibeing", and a "school" is an "eduviron"). It was quite intriguing to untangle the meaning of some of the sentences. A small glossary is available [here](http://luna.randomstatic.net/technotalk.php#s).

The episode titles were also rendered into Technotalk. They seem to be jokes or puns, or parodies of well-known sayings. I've done my best to translate them, but there are a few that defeat me. I'd appreciate any help on the ones I can't get, together with comments on whether you think my translations are correct.

Ultra-gratitudes for your tocks!

Season 1

1. *Habiviron, Sweet Habiviron* = Home, Sweet Home
2. *The Clunkman Cometh* = (no idea)
3. *All The World's A Teletalk Linkup* = All the world’s a stage
4. *Happy Batch Day Dear Luna* = Happy Birthday Dear Luna
5. *Environmental Ambience Stable, Wish You Were Here* = Weather’s nice, wish you were here
6. *When Did You Last See Your Pater Batch Mix Donor* = When did you last see your father?

Season 2

1. *You Can't Judge a Videotalker by its Blurb* = You can’t judge a book by its cover
2. *Go Forth and Quadruplicate* = Go forth and multiply
3. *The Happiest Earth Revolves of Your Span* = The happiest days of your life
4. *It Isn't How You Vict or Slunk But How You Co-participate* = (no idea)
5. *A Bureaubureau In The Hand Is Worth A Pension* = (no idea)
6. *You're Only As Multi-Tocked As You Perceive* = You’re only as old as you feel

Comment: I witnessed its broadcast in New Zealand.

Comment: 'One of its most distinctive features was the futuristic language, Technotalk, that the characters spoke. It was a little like Orwell's Newspeak in some ways'  Superficially perhaps, but Technotalk describes things _more_ precisely and analytically than standard English, whereas a key purpose of Newspeak is to _prevent_ things from being described precisely or analytically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Community wiki answer, feel free to improve.

Season 1

1. *Habiviron, Sweet Habiviron* = Home, Sweet Home
2. *The Clunkman Cometh* = [The Iceman Cometh](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Iceman_Cometh)
3. *All The World's A Teletalk Linkup* = [All the world’s a stage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_the_world%27s_a_stage)
4. *Happy Batch Day Dear Luna* = Happy Birthday Dear Luna
5. *Environmental Ambience Stable, Wish You Were Here* = Weather’s nice, wish you were here
6. *When Did You Last See Your Pater Batch Mix Donor* = [When did you last see your father?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Frederick_Yeames#And_When_Did_You_Last_See_Your_Father?)

Season 2

1. *You Can't Judge a Videotalker by its Blurb* = You can’t judge a book by its cover
2. *Go Forth and Quadruplicate* = Go forth and multiply
3. *The Happiest Earth Revolves of Your Span* = [The happiest days of your life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Happiest_Days_of_Your_Life_(play))
4. *It Isn't How You Vict or Slunk But How You Co-participate* = It's not the winning or losing that counts, it's the taking part
5. *A Bureaubureau In The Hand Is Worth A Pension* = A bird in the hand is worth two in the bush
6. *You're Only As Multi-Tocked As You Perceive* = You’re only as old as you feel

Comment: Arghh, I should have got the "It matters not who won or lost..." one. Still not sure about s02e05 though, somehow it doesn't sound quite right.

Comment: Yeah, that one seems a lot more tortured than the others, but the "... in the hand is worth ..." is pretty surely a reference to that phrase. Maybe there's another reference mixed in, but maybe they just couldn't come up with anything better that week.

Comment: 2.4. is probably "It’s not whether you win or lose, it’s how you play the game" which I believe the the proper expression.

Comment: "When the great scorer comes to write against your name, He marks not that you have won or lost, but how you played the game."  Grantland Rice.

Comment: @IMSoP I was wondering if s02e05 may be something of a mangled 'A something is worth its weight in gold'. 'worth its weight in gold' might match 'pension' better. I'm just not sure about the 'in the hand bit.

Comment: S02E04 "It's not the winning or losing that counts, it's the taking part". Usually the phrase is "It's not the winning or losing that counts, it's how you play the game." Of course, when I say "usual", that's an American perspective, and this may well be _exactly_ the British version of the saying.